# how to make one screen working for mutlple tasks in android

Tags: android, button

I want to make an android app which contains four buttons on top of screen and when pressing each button i need different screens below those four buttons.please tell how to make it.

Comment: Google is your friend   https://www.google.co.in/webhp?tab=ww&ei=caZ9VND9L4uPuASL4YG4Bw&ved=0CAYQ1S4#q=Android+Fragments+examples

Comment: Are you creating like tabview? http://androidexample.com/Tab_Layout_%7C_TabBar_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=103&aaid=125

Comment: Use tabs and fragments. Without learning you can't implement it. Get started here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: It's called an ActionBar (lately, ToolBar). Or a TabBar. You can even make your own Button Bar, for more customization freedom.

Comment: You may use Fragment. Here is example 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

Comment: i want four buttons on top of screen like length converter,area converter,temp converter,time converter.below that i need length conversion screen when i pressed length converter button. but four buttons remains on top of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Use Fragment...
You can build an activity that contains 1 fragment for buttons, and one view for replace it with a fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        class:"com.example.ButtonFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/button_fragment" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/LayoutForReplace"/>
```

Then you can set action listener of buttons like this:

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(r.id.LayoutForRepalce, new SomeFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: @subhakarpatnala: don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful. Tnx

Comment: how to accept?@K2evil

Comment: @subhakarpatnala there is a tick sign in left side of my answer that you have to click on it. then its color turn into green...

Comment: i have used fragments.but how to get active the fragment in main activity. it is not possible to use setContentView method in fragment class. please help me..